# "Traduzir" data retornada em português para inglês

Tags: php

Boa noite gente!

Estou com um problema em um script php atrelado ao cms phpbb, que retorna os tópicos de determinados fóruns e os apresenta em formato RSS 2.0.

O problema é que a data, ao ser processada pelo método do próprio phpbb [`format_date`](https://wiki.phpbb.com/User_class), sob o formato `"D, d M Y H:i:s O"`, é retornada com os valores de dia e mês em português, e eu preciso desses valores em inglês, pois os serviços que eu uso acabam bugando com a data em português.

Eu tinha visto em outras perguntas aqui no stack sobre a possibilidade de alterar o locale para fazer tal processamento, mas tenho dúvidas da eficácia disso sob o ecossistema do phpbb.

Um detalhe imporante é que o dado original a ser filtrado por esse método (variável `$topic_date`) é uma timestamp UNIX, o que significa que pode ser usada em outra função, e que, segundo a documentação do método, posso usar qualquer formato aceito pela função date() do php na função `format_date`.

**EDIT:** Resumindo:

O PHPBB pode me retornar uma timestamp ou no formato próprio do RSS, mas com os nomes em português:

```
<pubDate>Qui, 02 Out 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

Mas eu preciso dele em inglês (pois deu duplicação em serviços como o twitterfeed), exatamente nesse formato:

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

Então, existe uma forma de se fazer isso?

Grato desde já.

Comment: Está confuso. Não poderia configurar pelo CMS do PHPBB? E outro ponto confuso é que não está claro se pretende traduzir de português para inglês ou apenas mudar o formato visual da data para o formato ISO 8601, o qual muitos atribuem erroneamente como "formato americano" ou "formato em inglês". Portanto, seja mais objetivo postando exemplo prático de como está atualmente a data e como quer que fique. Exemplo "21-02-2016" quer que fique como "2016-02-21"?

Comment: Desculpe a confusão sobre isso. Não dá pra configurar pelo PHPBB pois aí ele altera para todo o fórum, algo que não ficaria muito bom no design.
Sobre o formato ISO 8601, bom, não é exatamente o [site do php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) e algumas outras perguntas no stack recomendam.
Sobre o formato desejado, editarei a própria pergunta